# Залил сайт на хостинг beget и вижу ошибку Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.0.0"

Tags: php, wordpress, хостинг

Залил сайт на wordpress на хостинг beget и вижу ошибку Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.0.0". Локально запускается-все норм. Это адрес сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Надо узнать , какая версия PHP на сайте, а потом производить действия. На Вашем хостинге похоже старый PHP

Comment: К комментарию выше см ещё: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Узнайте версию PHP на сервере. Обычно это обозначается где-то в условиях хостинга сервера. Либо, если у вас есть доступ к терминалу сервера, то посмотрите там

Например, если linux система, то что-то подобное

```
php -v
```

Если есть возможность, обновите php на сервере. Если такой возможности нет, остается сменить сервер/хостинг или попросить техподдержку

Comment: Проверил версию- PHP: 5.6.40. Видимо хостинг буду менять. Может посоветуете, что нибудь?

Comment: Если у вас платный хостинг, то обратитесь к техподдержке, должны помочь. Версия 5.6 очень старая, и годится разве что для существующих legacy проектов. Можете сами попробовать обновить php ещё `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade`, либо воспользоваться руководством, например этим https://www.reg.ru/qa/t/kak-obnovit-php-7-0-33-do-7-4-7-v-ubuntu-16-04-nginx/98

Comment: Beget позволяет переключать версии php.